# How to create a 'past 3 months' time period in Google Data Studio

Tags: date-range, calculated-field, looker-studio

I'm trying to have my line chart show data for the past 3 months. GDS has a 'last quarter' date range, but this shows me Q1, Q2, Q3, or Q4. What I need is the data for the past 3 full months (not counting the current month). I tried creating a calculated field but the documentation isn't proving very useful for the matter at hand.

eg. If the current date is Feb-20, I want to show data from 'Nov 1 - Jan 31'. Also need to compare to same period from last year.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option "advanced" in the date dropdown and set the start date to today minus 3 months.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible in the way you're describing. You can achieve the same by creating a metric in your data source and then applying a filter at the page / chart / report level to remove data which doesn't meet your criteria

Answer (score 0):

"Start Date - 3 Months Ago."
Use the following formula: TODAY() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
Create a Calculated Field for the End Date:

Create another calculated field.
Name it something like "End Date - Last Month."
Use the following formula: TODAY() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
Filter Your Data:

Apply a filter to your data source.
Choose the field that represents your date or timestamp.
Set the filter to include dates between "Start Date - 3 Months Ago" and "End Date - Last Month."
Now, your chart should show data for the past 3 full months, not including the current month. To compare this period to the same period from the previous year, you can duplicate the data source and use these new fields for the comparison, adjusting the date range accordingly.

Remember to replace "TODAY()" with the current date if you're using a different date field as your reference.